# How to group this list in to some group whose element have a same number to relate

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this `list`

```
list={{0,7},{16,0},{16,2},{12,5},{11,1},{1,20},{3,20}};
```

This is my current method to realize it.

```
ConnectedComponents@RelationGraph[IntersectingQ, list]
```

> {{{16, 2}, {16, 0}, {0, 7}}, {{11, 1}, {1, 20}, {3, 20}}, {{12, 5}}}

But are there ***non-graph and concise*** solution can implement this target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is ugly,I don't like the `If` here especially,anyway it works.:)

```
list = {{0, 7}, {16, 0}, {16, 2}, {12, 5}, {11, 1}, {1, 20}, {3, 20}};
FixedPoint[
 Function[l, temp = Gather[l, ContainsAny[Flatten@#, Flatten[#2]] &]; 
  If[Depth[temp] > 4, Catenate/@temp, temp]], list]
```

> {{{0, 7}, {16, 0}, {16, 2}}, {{12, 5}}, {{11, 1}, {1, 20}, {3, 20}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{0, 7}, {16, 0}, {16, 2}, {12, 5}, {11, 1}, {1, 20}, {3, 20}};

EdgeList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents@
   Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ list] /.
 UndirectedEdge -> List

(*  {{{16, 2}, {16, 0}, {0, 7}}, {{11, 1}, {1, 20}, {3, 20}}, {{12, 5}}}  *)
```

Very slightly shorter,

```
Apply[List,
 EdgeList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents@
   Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ list], {2}]

(*  {{{16, 2}, {16, 0}, {0, 7}}, {{11, 1}, {1, 20}, {3, 20}}, {{12, 5}}}  *)

% === %%

(*  True  *)
```

Without using any `Graph` functions you can get equivalent (graphs are undirected) but differently ordered results.

```
list = {{0, 7}, {16, 0}, {16, 2}, {12, 5}, {11, 1}, {1, 20}, {3, 20}};

Partition[#, 2, 
   1] & /@ (list //. {{s___, {x1_, i1___, y1_}, m___, {y1_, i2___, y2_}, 
      e___} :>
     {s, {x1, i1, y1, i2, y2}, m, e},
    {s___, {x1_, i1___, y1_}, m___, {x2_, i2___, x1_}, e___} :>
     {s, {x2, i2, x1, i1, y1}, m, e},
    {s___, {x1_, i1___, y1_}, m___, {x1_, i2___, y2_}, e___} :>
     {s, {y2, Sequence@Reverse@{i2}, x1, i1, y1}, m, e},
    {s___, {x1_, i1___, y1_}, m___, {x2_, i2___, y1_}, e___} :>
     {s, {x1, i1, y1, Sequence@Reverse@{i2}, x2}, m, e}, {} :> Nothing})

(*  {{{2, 16}, {16, 0}, {0, 7}}, {{12, 5}}, {{11, 1}, {1, 20}, {20, 3}}}  *)
```

Comment: Thinks for your concerning.But so many pattern is hard to understand for me.:)And I have a new thinking about it,I'll post it later.